# JavaScript display buttons when option is selected

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<select name="numbers" onchange="buttons(this)">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="add"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="add"></div>
<div id="editDelete"><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = ""; // I call this function with `<body onload="load()">`
}

function buttons(data) {
    if (data.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Add" name="add">';
        return;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">';
        document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
}
```

So when I load the page, there's only one button "Add", when I select any option "Add" disappears and "Edit" and "Delete" show up. But when I select the option `<option value=""></option>`, "Add" doesnt' show up. Am I missing something or do I have the code wrong?

Comment: `if` statements need an expression, you only have 1 equals: `if (data.value = "") {` - that statement will always eval to true

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually retyped the code because I can't copy it and dropped one equal mark.

Comment: Your code is working fine. there is nothing to change

Comment: @Jake745 If it did work, I wouldn't have written here in the first place... I tried the code on `jsfiddle` and the code doesn't work there as well.

Comment: Yes its not working in jsfiddle ! Can i provide Jquery for your solution ?

Comment: Sure, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ntqw73h4/)

HTML:

1
        2
        3

```
<div id="add">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add"></div>
<div id="editDelete">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" />
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            load();
        });

        load();

        function load() {
            document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = ""; // I call this function with `<body onload="load()">`
        }

        $("#btn").change(function () {
            buttons(this);
        });

        function buttons(data) {
            if (data.value == "") {
                document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Add" name="add">';
                return;
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">';
                document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is modified code. You can achieve same with pure javascript.

## **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ue1knyt9/)**

```
  <html>
        <script>    
           document.onreadystatechange = function () {
                document.getElementById('editDelete').innerHTML = ""; 
            }

            function buttons(data) {        
                if (data.value == "") {
                    document.getElementById('editDelete').innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />';
                    return;
                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById("editDelete").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" />';
                    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }  
            }
        </script>
    <body>
        <select name="numbers" onchange="buttons(this)">
           <option value=""></option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <div id="add"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="add"></div>
        <div id="editDelete"><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" /></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```